# Image Entropy Value Error: Image dimensions and neighborhood dimensions do not match

Tags: python, scikit-image, entropy

I am working on a project and I am just getting started with Python programming. I am using Pycharm.
I want to extract the frames from a video and get the entropy in each frame and then save them.

I followed this tutorial:https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#skimage.filters.rank.entropy

This is my code so far:

```
import cv2
from skimage.filters.rank import entropy
from skimage.morphology import disk

filename = 'C:/Users/myname/Downloads/testvideo.mp4'
video = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

if not video.isOpened():
    print("Error opening video file")

i = 0
while video.isOpened():
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    img = entropy(frame, disk(5))
    cv2.imwrite('frame' + str(i) + '.jpg', img)
    i = i + 1

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Opening the video and saving the frames worked perfectly fine until I tried to apply the entropy to it the frames.

I have tried things like:

`img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

which worked perfectly fine and converted one frame to grayscale and saved them but there seems to be an issue with the entropy or more specifically the disk(5).

The error shown is:

ValueError: Image dimensions and neighborhood dimensions do not match

I get the same error when I try to run the code from the tutorial website.
Can anyone help me with this, please?
Thank you very much!

Comment: _I get the same error when I try to run the code from the tutorial website._ Do you get the error, when you run the example there without any modifications?

Comment: @HansHirse Yes, the same error still appears

Comment: That's kind of mysterious... If I run the example from the documentation, there's no error at all. Which version of SciPy do you use? Have you tried updating it (if applicable)?

Comment: @HansHirse The version is 1.6.2

Comment: @HansHirse Okay, I just tried running the example again and it works now. For my code, I still run into the same issue

Comment: I (still) can't reproduce your error, for some test MP4. Do you have `img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` and `img = entropy(frame, disk(5))`? Please pay attention, that you'd need to write `img = entropy(img, disk(5))`! Otherwise, you - again - would try to access the original (colored) `frame`.

Comment: Indeed, I think the issue here is that you are passing `frame` to `entropy`, where `frame` is a 3D array of shape (Nrows, Ncols, 3) (3 color channels) instead of a 2D array of shape (Nrows, Ncols).

Comment: You can use `skimage.color.rgb2gray()` to convert to grayscale before using `entropy`, though you might need to use `frame[..., ::-1]` to reverse the last channel if your image is actually BGR instead of RGB. (Or use @HansHirse's cv2 suggestion as above.)

Answer (score 3):

From the source code in skimage, when

```
footprint = np.ascontiguousarray(img_as_ubyte(footprint > 0))
if footprint.ndim != image.ndim:
    raise ValueError('Image dimensions and neighborhood dimensions'
                     'do not match')
```

the exception raised. footprint = disk(n). n=5 in your case.

So you can check the ndim of target image (img.ndim) and compare it with 2 (the ndim of disk(5)). If not equal, can use img = np.squeeze(img) to change image's ndim.

Comment: great answer! What does disk(5) mean?